# Android Studio - library versions conflict

Tags: android-studio, duplicates, dependencies, conflict

I get this error. I m guessing one of the libraries is importing a sub-library with version 15.0.1 and that's how the error is intoduced. If I can find which library is doing that maybe I could handle the situation.

How can I identify which library is causing the import of a specific sub library like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1` for example ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude sub-libraries like so:

```
implementation(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper-core', version: '0.10.alpha3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
}
```

Of course this is just an example. You'll have to apply it to your own case.
You can find what's in them by looking through the maven repo.
As an example:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphhopper/graphhopper-core/0.10.0

Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: i know...my questions is how to identify which library creates the problem.